# GAS: How can I skip already created calendar events when pulling from a sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to setup a script that will pull from a Google Sheet to create Google Calendar events, and skip ones that have already been created if the script runs again. Currently it is creating one event and overwriting it as it works through the list

'''

```
function CTOcalendar() {

// Set up sheet and calendar
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2'); 
var calendar = 
CalendarApp.getCalendarById("nsmvt.org_classroom3eda5899@group.calendar.google.com");

/** ... **/ 

var CTO = spreadsheet.getRange("A2:C100").getValues();

for (x=0; x < CTO.length; x++){

// retrieve one entry at a time
var entry = CTO[x];

// get start time from the 2nd column, column 1
var startTime = new Date(entry[1]);

// get end time from the 3rd column, column 2
var endTime = new Date(entry[2]);

// retrieve name from the 1st column, column 0
var name = entry[0];

/** ... **/

// ... within for loop

// if name is missing/empty skip 
// this entry 
if (name == ''){continue;}

// get events during the start and end times
// specified above
var conflicts = calendar.getEvents(startTime, endTime);

//  if the length of conflicts is 0, create an event directly
if (conflicts.length == 0){
  createAndShare(calendar, name, startTime, endTime);
} 
// if the length of conflict is larger than 0
// iterate through the conflicting events
else {
  for (c=0; c < conflicts.length; c++){
    // load one conflict at a time
    var conflict = conflicts[c]

    // if title of conflict matches name
    // skip this conflicting event
    if (conflict.getTitle() == name){continue;}

    // create new event 
    create(calendar, name, startTime, endTime);
  } 
}
} 
}

function create(cal, title, start, end){
// create event with provided title, start
// start and end time
var event = cal.createEvent(title, start, end);
}
```

'''

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could check a checkbox in your sheet when the row is set as an event. And filter out the ones that are checked. Or you could get the eventID from the created event end then you could use that to update a event later on if you extend the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Proposed solution

First of all, when doing such operations you should keep track of the cell indexes so you can directly apply an update if needed.

There are various solutions that allow you to skip the event creation if it already exists; here are a few:

- Once the event is created you can put a checkbox at the end its row:

```
// Filter the values by their Checkbox state
var CTO = spreadsheet.getRange("A2:C100").getValues().filter(row => !row[checkbox_col_index]);
// create the event since the checkbox isn't checked. 
// At the end check the checkbox setting the cell value to `true`
```

- Register the eventId in its event row, this can be useful to update it in the future as well

Same as before just filter the rows if the eventId column is empty and once the event is created fill the cell with the `event.getId()` return value.

### References

[CalendarEvent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event)